# Are any matrices positive semidefinite, non-negative, and not diagonally dominated?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, spectral-theory

If so, I'd appreciate any examples. Thanks.

Comment: What does “diagonally dominated” mean exactly ? $|a_{ii}|$ is larger than all the $|a_{ij}|$ for $j\neq i$ ?

Comment: What about say $3\times 3$ matrix with all its entries being 1?

Comment: @Tapu : that’s not positive semi-definite.

Comment: A matrix is said to be diagonally dominant if for every row of the matrix, the magnitude of the diagonal entry in a row is larger than or equal to the sum of the magnitudes of all the other (non-diagonal) entries in that row.

Comment: Diagonally dominant is very easy to avoid: just make one diagonal entry small.

Comment: That is, for all $i$, $a_{ij} \ge \sum_{i\ne j} |a_{ij}|$.

Comment: @ErickWong : But will it still be PSD then?

Comment: @Jeff Not always, but there are plenty of examples if you just try a few $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $2\times 2$ positive (symmetric) matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&d\end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite iff its determinant $ad-b^2$ is positive.  If $a>b$, then it is very easy to choose $d < b$ such that $ad > b^2$, making it positive definite but not diagonally dominant.

Answer (score 1):

For all $n\ge3$, the $n\times n$ matrix $J_n$ with all entries equal to $1$ is nonnegative, positive semidefinite ($x^\ast J_nx=|\sum_ix_i|^2\ge0$) and not diagonally dominant.